# Find connected IBAction in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, ios, interface-builder

I'm debugging a certain method in a pre-existing project (call it foobarPressed).  It's listed as an IBAction, but I can't figure out where in the UI to go to trigger this method, and the original developer is unavailable.

When I open the three views associated with the controller it's in and look at the events for each button, each has something connected but none has foobarPressed.

Is there a way to search all connections in Interface Builder?  Barring that, is there a way to search IB elements by linked identifier (so I could find the button referenced in the code as btnFoobar)?  The search field in the .xib view only seems to allow searching by name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure about doing a search, but I find it often handy to click to highlight the File's Owner in the Document window, and then go to the Connections Inspector in the Inspector window.  You should see a Received Actions section with all the IBAction items defined in the class for the File's Owner, and you can see right away if an IBAction is connected to an event for any of the controls in the NIB file.

Comment: Thanks!  This made it a LOT easier to do what I wanted.

Comment: Yeah thanks I noticed that my IBAction didn't have a round button thingy but rather a little Dr Mario pill looking thing. Turns out this wasn't connected to anything so it was nowhere to be found in code. I really wish they would make a way to get to code from an IB connection